# Spring Boot Jpa jakarta not fetching ManyToMany data

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a problem that I tried to isolate and I still don't get what's wrong.
I have 2 classes (entities) -> Teacher and Student and the table for the many to many relation (StudentTeacherRelation) with @EmbeddableId.

The problem is that when I retrieve a collection of teachers from the db, it doesn't retrieve the students data that are linked with that teacher (the many to many relation). Back with javax.persistence it worked, but now that I'm using jakarta.persistence it doesn't work that way and I want to know why.

As for dependencies, I have Spring Web, Spring Data JPA, Lombok and PostgreSQL Driver

The code:

--------------------------- Models ----------------------------

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class StudentTeacherKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private UUID teacher_id;

    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long student_id;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_TEACHER")
@Data
public class StudentTeacherRelation {

    @JsonIgnore
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentTeacherKey id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("student_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("teacher_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @Column(name = "extra_column")
    private String extraColumn;

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHERS")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID teacher_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<StudentTeacherRelation> students = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long student_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<StudentTeacherRelation> teacher = new HashSet<>();
}
```

--------------------------- Repo ----------------------------

```
public interface TeacherRepo extends JpaRepository<Teacher, UUID> {
}
```

```
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

--------------------------Service-------------------------------

```
public interface TeacherService {
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers();
}
```

```
@Service
public class TeacherServiceImpl implements TeacherService{

    private final TeacherRepo teacherRepo;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherServiceImpl(TeacherRepo teacherRepo) {
        this.teacherRepo = teacherRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
        return new HashSet<>(teacherRepo.findAll());
    }
}
```

------------------------------Controller--------------------------------

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/teacher")
public class TeacherController {

    private final TeacherService teacherService;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherController(TeacherService teacherService) {
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
        return teacherService.getAllTeachers();
    }
}
```

This is what I got

> [
> {
> "teacher_id": "467f4868-928e-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002",
> "name": "Teacher",
> "students": []
> } ]

I should've got the students that are linked to each teacher as well.

I updates the example to be more clear why I want this kind of method -> having extra columns in the join table.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging to see the SQL generated by JPA (Hibernate?). From the mappings, the Teacher.students relationship is marked as Lazy, so you may need to fetch the relationship before you pass it up the stack to be serialized to JSON. This might be as simple iterating over the Set<Teacher> collection and touching each StudentTeacherRelation's Student.

Comment: You haven't turned on SQL logging to see what is generated - no one can tell you what 'else' might be going wrong without more information. Are you sure there is data in the DB? How are you 'writing' these to the database? I just noticed that you are using Lombok -  make sure it isn't generating equals and hashcode implementations that break your set functionality. What versions of Spring was this working on that it isn't now?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you've described is a common way to handle many-to-many relationships in Java with Spring and JPA. However, there are a few potential issues and improvements to consider:

1. **Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading:** Your use of `FetchType.LAZY` in the `@OneToMany` relationships in the `Teacher` and `Student` entities is a standard practice to enhance performance. However, it also means that the related entities are not loaded until they are explicitly accessed in your code. This is likely why the students' data is not being retrieved when you fetch the teachers. If you need to load the related entities immediately, you can switch to `FetchType.EAGER`. But, be cautious with eager loading as it can lead to performance issues, especially if you have large datasets or complex entity graphs.
2. **Jackson Serialization and Lazy Loading:** In a typical Spring Boot application, Jackson is used to serialize entities to JSON. With lazy loading, Jackson may encounter issues serializing these entities because the lazily-loaded collections are not initialized at serialization time. To resolve this, you can either initialize these collections manually before serialization or use Hibernate's `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to ignore them. However, a better approach might be to use Data Transfer Objects (DTOs). DTOs allow you to selectively send the data you need over the network, avoiding issues related to lazy loading and also adding an extra layer of abstraction between your internal data model and what you expose to the users.
3. **Using DTOs:** Directly exposing entities can lead to several issues, including the aforementioned lazy loading problem. DTOs are a pattern where you create separate classes specifically for data transfer purposes. These classes can be tailored to the exact data requirements of your API consumers, avoiding the need to send unnecessary data and helping to decouple your API layer from your database model. By using DTOs, you can manually load the necessary data into the DTOs, effectively bypassing the problems associated with lazy loading and Jackson serialization.

#### Conclusion

In summary, while lazy loading is beneficial for performance, it can complicate serialization and data retrieval in APIs. Using DTOs offers a way to circumvent these issues, providing more control over the data exposed through your API and potentially improving application performance and maintainability.

Comment: I tried the EAGER fetching as well and it doesn't work. As for DTOs and JSON, that's not the problem, at least not yet, as the data is not even taken from the db. When I try to debug the app and to see what the repo brings from the db there is no student fetched in the student HashSet from teachers. 
Do you have any other suggestion that might help? I'm still trying to find the reason of why it doesn't work the way it should (or at least the way it worked with javax).

Comment: Check my new post @[Sicu Bogdan Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23037568/sicu-bogdan-andrei)

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code

In the original code, the many-to-many relationship between `Teacher` and `Student` was managed through an intermediate entity `StudentTeacherRelation`. This approach involved a composite key (`StudentTeacherKey`) to handle the relationship. Each `Teacher` and `Student` entity had a `Set` of `StudentTeacherRelation` to represent the association.

#### Issues with your code

- **Complexity:** The use of an intermediate entity with a composite key added complexity to the relationship management.
- **Lazy Loading:** The `LAZY` fetch type in the relationship meant that related entities were not loaded unless explicitly accessed, leading to issues in data retrieval.
- **Data Retrieval:** It seemed that the students associated with a teacher were not being retrieved from the database, possibly due to misconfiguration or issues with lazy loading.

#### My code (at the end of this post)

The refactored code uses a direct `@ManyToMany` annotation in the `Teacher` and `Student` entities, eliminating the need for the intermediate `StudentTeacherRelation` entity.

#### Changes I made

- **Direct Many-to-Many Mapping:** Used `@ManyToMany` along with `@JoinTable` in both `Teacher` and `Student` entities. This directly maps the two entities, simplifying the relationship.
- **Removal of Intermediate Entity:** The `StudentTeacherRelation` entity and `StudentTeacherKey` are removed, reducing complexity and potential sources of error.
- **Transactional Annotation:** Added `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to the service method to ensure proper handling of transactions, especially important for lazy loading of entities.

#### Why these changes?

- **Simplification:** The direct many-to-many mapping is a more straightforward and conventional way to handle such relationships in JPA. It reduces complexity and aligns with standard practices.
- **Improved Readability and Maintenance:** Removing the intermediate entity and composite key makes the code easier to understand and maintain.
- **Potential Resolution of Lazy Loading Issues:** By restructuring the relationships and ensuring proper transactional boundaries, the issues related to lazy loading and data retrieval might be resolved.

#### Summary

The refactored code aims to provide a cleaner, more maintainable, and potentially more functional approach to managing a many-to-many relationship in a Spring Boot application with JPA. It simplifies the relationship mapping and aligns with common JPA practices, potentially resolving issues encountered with the initial complex setup.

---

#### Teacher.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHERS")
@Data
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "teacher_id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "STUDENT_TEACHER",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
}
```

#### Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

#### StudentRepo.java

```
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {}
```

#### TeacherRepo.java

```
public interface TeacherRepo extends JpaRepository<Teacher, UUID> {}
```

#### TeacherService.java

```
public interface TeacherService {
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers();
}
```

#### TeacherServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class TeacherServiceImpl implements TeacherService {

    private final TeacherRepo teacherRepo;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherServiceImpl(TeacherRepo teacherRepo) {
        this.teacherRepo = teacherRepo;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
        return new HashSet<>(teacherRepo.findAll());
    }
}
```

#### TeacherController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/teacher")
public class TeacherController {

    private final TeacherService teacherService;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherController(TeacherService teacherService) {
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public Set<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
        return teacherService.getAllTeachers();
    }
}
```

PS: `@Data` is from [Lombok](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I would like to also know what can I do if I need to add additional columns to the join table? That's mainly why I want to know what's the problem with the above example.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating the realtion tables on your own, and setting them as the ManyToMany mapping relation.
The overall mapping is wrong - Please refer to- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many . Follow the example, should be helpful.

Comment: This could be mapped as a M:M, but mapping the relational table as an Entity is a valid representation of the data, and quite common when other values exist in the relation.

Comment: There are 2 ways of mapping the ManyToMany relation with JPA and this one is used when adding more columns to the join table. I know this example doesn't have more columns, but I want to know what's the problem here because it should work (at least it worked back at javax) and because it is a common way for adding additional columns in the join table.